# batch file If exist timeout

Tags: batch-file

I tried following code:

```
if exist "\\%1\c$\users\Public\" (
set sysos=Windows 7
) else (
set sysos=Windows XP
)
```

But when they can't find `\\computername\c$` it takes more than 20 seconds for a time out. How can I create a shorter timeout in the code?

Comment: you want a time-out or you have unwanted timeout?

Comment: I tried clarifying the question based on what I think you were trying to ask. If I guessed incorrectly then please edit the question to better highlight what you are wanting accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this solves your issue:

```
set "sysos="
ping -n 1 %1 >nul && if exist "\\%1\c$\users\Public\" (
      set sysos=Windows 7
   ) else (
      set sysos=Windows XP
   )
if not defined sysos echo %1 server is offline
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it. It safes a lot of time.

Comment: Very useful! Explanation for `&&`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889954/what-does-in-this-batch-file

Answer (score 2):

May be with `WMIC` commands it will work faster ?

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f  delims^= %%a in ('wmic /node:%~1 os get version /format:Wmiclivalueformat') do (
    for /f %%O in ("%%~a") do set "%%O"

)
set /a version=%version:.=%

if %version% LSS 620000 if %version% GEQ 610000(
    set "sysos=Windows 7"
)

if %version% LEQ 520000 if %version% GEQ 510000(
    set "sysos=Windows XP"
)

echo %sysos%
endlocal
```

Does not check if the remote machine exists...