# What does "&&" do in this batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, syntax

I received a line of code from someone who answered one of my questions, but I am confused: what do the "&&" do in this batch file.

```bat
@echo off
set /p Quest="How are you today? "
echo %Quest% > Results.txt
findstr /r /i "not.*good not.*well" Results.txt >nul && echo Sorry && goto pause
findstr /i "good well" Results.txt >nul && echo My day is doing good as well
:pause
pause
```

Comment: Wow, http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: @Mathemats Thanks for linking me to website, it has everything I need.

Comment: It's definitely a good beginning site, but take note that a good chunk of it is outdated or obsolete - everything on the `debug` page, for example.

Comment: @SomethingDark Okay, I will keep that in mind while I learn from it.

Comment: The "eqivalent to" column on that page is not eqivalent when output redirection is used, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358437/1941779

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`&&` runs the second command on the line when the first command comes back successfully (i.e. `errorlevel == 0`). The opposite of `&&` is `||`, which runs the second command when the first command is unsuccessful (i.e. `errorlevel != 0`).

Comment: Here's a reference page for Win XP (lol) but still contains helpful information.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @user4317867 the link is broken

Comment: @Spandy: https://web.archive.org/web/20060412075633/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: All this stuff is on ss64.com https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: Watch out for a single `&`, which works, but doesn't check whether the previous command was successful.

Answer (score 173):

- `&`    separates commands on a line.
- `&&`    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.
- `||`    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0
- `>`    output to a file
- `>>`    append output to a file
- `<`    input from a file
- `|`    output of one command into the input of another command
- `^`    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program
- `"`    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes
- `+` used with `copy` to concatenate files. E.G. `copy file1+file2 newfile`
- `,` used with `copy` to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. `copy /b file1,,`
- `%variablename%` an inbuilt or user set environmental variable
- `!variablename!` a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command
- `%<number>` (`%1`) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. `%0` is the batchfile's name.
- `%*` (`%*`) the entire command line.
- `%<a letter>` or `%%<a letter>` (`%A` or `%%A`) the variable in a for loop. Single `%` sign at command prompt and double `%` sign in a batch file.

Comment: +1 for putting all that in one place. I don't understand the comma description. copy /b file1,, returned "The file cannot be copied to itself." I ran it from the command line. Would it do something different from within a batch file?

Comment: Where it comes from?

Comment: a clarification about one ampersand & "Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command. " 

So I understand, that commands separated with & runs sequential like with &&, but they run always (no matter the errorlevel of a previous command) –

Comment: Great info, but what is the source?