# Define multiple output dirs for resources in sourceSet in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have multi-project where I want to attach resources from different locations (sub-projects that generate them) but also place them in different output directories.

```
wrapper (parent)
|--frontend (child)
|  |--build/dist
|     |--js
|     |  |-- ...
|     |--css
|        |-- ...
|--lib (child)
   |--build/dist
      |--python
         |-- ...
```

I need for `wrapper (parent)` to treat both of child projects' `build/dist` as resource, BUT placed in different `outputDir`.

- `frontend/build/dist` would be in `./wrapper/build/resources/main/static`
- `lib/build/dist` would be in `./wrapper/build/resources/main`

Goal is to have given resource of sourceSet `main` be appended with `static` directory when moving it to `outputDir`.

Note that `outputDir` is NOT `jar` task. This is not packaging issue, but `outputDir` issue.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
             srcDirs [
                 project(':frontend').projectDir.absolutePath + '/build/dist'
                 project(':lib').projectDir.absolutePath + '/build/dist'
             ]
        }
        output.resourcesDir project.buildDir.absolutePath + '/resources/main/static'
    }
}
```

Above will add resources to main sourceSet, but they will have the same output.resourceDir.

**Final questions**

1. Is there syntax that allows defining output for given src? Can you give me example?
2. If not (yet?), I though about defining more than one `sourceSet`. Basically define `main1` and `main2`, this would work fine, but I have some problems making those `sourceSets` be child of `main`. In other words - if you define custom `sourceSet` (not `main` or `test`) you need to make it compile - **how**? I know I can command: `gradle build sourceSetName` to invoke specific custom `sourceSet` compilation, how can I do it so it is dependency to `main`?

I am using Gradle 4.10.1 with java (and eclipse) plugins.

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52521936/549372 ...because what you do is merging resource directories - which only might work when the destination sub-directories are already present in the two `srcDirs`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I was considering creating "fake" task pipeline imitating copying (Gradle uses Copy task to resources->outputDir), but I really want to preserve mechanism of java plugin because it's base for generating IDE classpaths (eclipse in my case). If I go this way I will also have to define whole bunch of eclipse configurations to mirror gradle's build process. Using only sourceSets (if such syntax exists) setups unified front with IDE plugins.
For now I will also try generating /static/ already in dist folder, but in future that might not be enough (this thread is simplified problem).

Comment: these are `resources { }` `SourceSet` ...to add `build/dist` as `srcDirs` seems strange. in general, `src` should be the build input, not the build output. version control hooks can also be used for such automation ...eg. to have a further repository, which performs to combined build.