# How To change Android App Bundles name (app.aab) to reflect App version and build type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

While I'm building an APK I can change APK name in `build.gradle` script, like that:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  if (variant.buildType.name != "debug") {
      variant.outputs.all {
          outputFileName = "${variant.applicationId}-v${variant.versionName}-${variant.name}.apk"
      }
  }
}
```

An I'll have something like this `com.myapp.package-v1.x.x-release`

Is there a way to do something similar with Android App Bundles, it is not convenient to always have `app.aab`

Comment: There is no link added in here

Comment: For me, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508858/6835732) did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with the solution of how to achieve this with Gradle.

First, we have to create in App `build.gradle` file a Gradle task that will rename the original `app.aab` on copy. This method is described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:renaming_files_example).
Then for conveniance, we will add another method that will delete old `app.aab` file.

```
android{ 
.....
}
dependencies{
.....
}
.....

task renameBundle(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/release"
    into "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/release"

    rename 'app.aab', "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.aab"
}

task deleteOriginalBundleFile(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree("$buildDir/outputs/bundle/release").matching {
        include "app.aab"
    }
}
```

In this example the output file name will be something like `1.5.11.aab`
Then we can combine those tasks together into `publishRelease` task which will be used for publishing the App:

```
task publishRelease(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['clean', 'assembleRelease', 'bundleRelease', 'renameBundle', 'deleteOriginalBundleFile']
}
```

Comment: How do you run publishRelease? How do I make it automatically call when I generate a signed APK into the specified directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    ...

    this.project.afterEvaluate { project ->
        project.tasks.each { task ->
            if (task.toString().contains("packageReleaseBundle")) {
                task.doLast {
                    copy {
                        from "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/release"
                        into "${projectDir}/../../../../publish/android/"

                        rename "app.aab", "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.aab"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You should add a bit of explanation, not only the code.