# Android appbundle: rename generated outputfile (.aab)

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am trying to rename the generated `.aab` file in format `<appname>-<variant>-<buildType>-<version>`, is there any way output bundle file can be renamed similar to apk renaming.

Copying and renaming I have tried, but the problem there is I need to name the bundle as `<appname>-<variant>-<buildType>-<version>`. when I create the task as mentioned here [How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508720/how-to-change-the-generated-filename-for-app-bundles-with-gradle)
getting the variant is using a substring, which gives both `variantBuildtype`.

Answer (score 5):

First I'd like to clarify what a build variant is.
A build variant is a combination of the build type and flavor.
For example, a build type could be `release` and a flavor could be something like `freeVersion`. So a variant would be `releaseFreeVersion`.

*Note: the answer that you linked has a side effect of creating an additional copy of the `.aab` file rather than only renaming it. This answer also fixes that.*

## Part 1: This answer assumes you are using product flavors

In this answer I'll assume that you are using product flavors. I'll also assume the format you want is `<appname>-<flavor>-<buildType>-<version>`.

### First create some supplementary Gradle methods

You can add these toward the bottom of your `build.gradle` file (outside of all curly braces).

```
static String firstMatchingSubstring(String taskName, String[] keys) {
    def lcName = taskName.toLowerCase()

    for(String key: keys) {
        if(lcName.contains(key.toLowerCase())) return key
    }

    return null
}

/**
 *
 * @param taskName e.g., bundleMyFlavorRelease or bundleRelease
 * @return
 */
String getBuildType(String taskName) {
    return firstMatchingSubstring(taskName, getBuildTypeNames())
}

/**
 *
 * @param taskName e.g., bundleMyFlavorRelease
 * @return
 */
String getFlavor(String taskName) {
    return firstMatchingSubstring(taskName, getProductFlavorNames())
}

String[] getBuildTypeNames() {
    def types = []

    android.buildTypes.all { type ->
        types.add(type.name)
    }

    return types
}

String[] getProductFlavorNames() {
    def flavors = []

    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        flavors.add(flavor.name)
    }

    return flavors
}
```

### Create a task to rename the app bundle

Similar to the [accepted answer you linked in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010142/1159930) we'll insert a rename task.
I hard coded the app name but if you want to have different app names you could put them inside the `android.defaultConfig` block and then reference the name below.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def name = task.name

    //Skip some unnecessary tasks
    if (name.startsWith("bundle")
            && !name.contains("Classes")
            && !name.contains("Resources")
            && name != "bundle") {

        def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
        def version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}-${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}"
        def flavor = getFlavor(name)
        def type = getBuildType(name)
        if(flavor == null || type == null) return

        def outputName = "AppName-$flavor-$type-$version"

        tasks.create(renameTaskName) {
            def path = "${rootDir}/app/${flavor}/${type}/"
            def originalFile = "$path/app-${flavor}-${type}.aab"

            doLast {
                if (file("$originalFile").exists()) {
                    ant.move file: "$originalFile",
                            tofile: "$path/${outputName}.aab"
                }
            }
        }

        task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
    }
}
```

---

## Part 2: This answer assumes you are not using product flavors

If you are not using product flavors then something more simple like the [accepted answer you linked in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010142/1159930) with some modifications. This would produce a name like `<appname>-<buildType>-<version>.aab`.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def name = task.name

    //Skip some unnecessary tasks
    if (name.startsWith("bundle")
            && !name.contains("Classes")
            && !name.contains("Resources")
            && name != "bundle") {

        def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
        def type = task.name.substring("bundle".length()).uncapitalize()
        def version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}-${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}"
        def outputName = "AppName-$type-$version"

        tasks.create(renameTaskName) {
            def path = "${rootDir}/app/${type}/"
            def originalFile = "$path/app-${type}.aab"

            doLast {
                if (file("$originalFile").exists()) {
                    ant.move file: "$originalFile",
                            tofile: "$path/${outputName}.aab"
                }
            }
        }

        task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
    }
}
```