# Why isn't .aab file added -free-release or -pro-release.apk suffix automatically when I use the same build.gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I use the following build.gradle to generate .apk files, the result will be *MagnifyingGlass-V1.01-free-release.apk* for **free** edition and  *MagnifyingGlass-V1.01-pro-release.apk* for **pro** edition. *-free-release* or *-pro-release* is added to filename as suffix automatically by Android Studio 3.4.2.

I try to use the same  build.gradle to generate .aab files,  I find the result is *MagnifyingGlass-V1.01* for **free** and  *MagnifyingGlass-V1.01* for **pro**, there are same, why?  *-free-release* or *-pro-release* isn't added to filename as suffix automatically by Android Studio 3.4.2.

**Added content:**

I generated different edition .apk and .aab using Android Studio just like *Image 1*.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.dodata.magnifyingglass"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.02"
        archivesBaseName = "MagnifyingGlass-V" + versionName
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.magnifyingglass"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.magnifyingglass.pro"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "false"
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "true"
        }
    }

}
```

**Image 1**
[image]

Comment: How are you creating the aab? Through terminal, with run button or Generate apk or app bundle?

Comment: I create both  .aab and .apk in Android Studio 3.4.1

Comment: So there are _two_ generated apks/aabs?

Comment: Have you tried adding `dimension "default"` to each `productFlavor`?

Comment: Thanks！I get the same result after I added dimension "default" to each productFlavor.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the name of the bundle is being rigidly applied (there might be a relevant ticket available on the issue-tracker).
Once left a workaround here:  [How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52521936/549372)

This approach can also be used to finalize these flavors, *based upon their final task's name*. Another optimization would be, to use the [Apache Ant integration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:moving_files_example) on the generated bundle. For some reason (unknown to me), Gradle does not support move (rename) operations out-of-the-box.

This configuration appears pretty useless (and there might be other configurations missing):

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "true"
```

because in Java that is known as `BuildConfig.DEBUG`; better replace that with configuration `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` - and also add the corresponding `applicationIdSuffix ".release"` (which rather sounds alike the intended outcome); for example:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationIdSuffix ".release"
        ...
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you show some code? I only publish release edition for both free and pro.

Comment: The problem I met is : Android Studio can automatically add -free-release or -pro-release suffix for free or pro edition when I generate .apk file, but Android Studio doesn't add  -free-release or -pro-release suffix for free or pro edition when I generate .aab file

Comment: And more, I test your code, the 4 filenames (MagnifyingGlass-V1.01-free-release.apk, MagnifyingGlass-V1.01-pro-release.apk , MagnifyingGlass-V1.01,MagnifyingGlass-V1.01) haven't any change.

Comment: @HelloCW this does not affect the `.aab` the least and I won't copy and paste my own answer. The configuration above at least fixes the filenames for the `.apk`. The first line reads: *the name of the bundle is being rigidly applied*. Your so called "debug" build doesn't even have configuration `debuggable true`. I'd suggest to first make it working for debug/release mode and the add the flavors - not the other way around. Yesterday seen a bug on the issue tracker, that building `.aab` even removes other files in the output directory, which could interfere - unless moving the files elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, I will remove `buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "true"` because `BuildConfig.DEBUG` can return correct result.

Comment: And more, what I need to get different `.aab` filename when Android Studio generate free edition and pro edition under  release buildTypes. Do you mean that it's a bug of gradle?

Comment: [How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508720/how-to-change-the-generated-filename-for-app-bundles-with-gradle/52521936#52521936) only generate different filename for Release and Debug buildType, what I need to get different filename for Free and Pro edition under  Release  buildType.

Comment: @HelloCW I've already explain this above and I won't spoon you. as the question is written, with these mis-configured build-types, this is even barely reproducible and I'm probably too lazy to support your laziness. With the information provided, this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for poor English, I hope to confirm whether that is a bug all filenames are same when generate .`aab` files.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in gradle version 3.5.2 where the product flavor suffix is applied automatically.