# SolrConfig Override from SolrJ

Tags: cmd, solr, solrj, solrconfig

I am trying to use `SolrConfig API` to override `SolrConfig.xml` file, but failed. Cmd doesn't allow to use multi-line commands. Either way, I'd rather do everything from the `SolrJ API`, because my entire project is written in Java. Could Someone please tutor me briefly on how is that done?

If not, can you please explain how do I write multiple line commands?
Edit:
I should have included the command I tried running, sorry. this command is used to create a request handler:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/config -H 'Content-type:application/json'  -d '{
  "add-requesthandler" : {
"name": "/mypath",
"class":"solr.DumpRequestHandler",
"defaults":{ "x":"y" ,"a":"b", "wt":"json", "indent":true },
"useParams":"x"
}
}'
```

and the cmd takes it as one line as a time. Is this code even for cmd?
honestly though, I don't get the syntax in general.

Comment: Could you please show what you've attempted and what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to learn if there are multi-line commands in cmd.

If you mean to split a long command to multiple lines the answer is **YES**. Please refer to [Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-windows-vista-batch-bat-file).

If you mean to run multiple command at once the answer is again **YES**. Try:

```bat
command 1 && command 2 && command 3 [&& ...]
```

If you mean to run multiple commands in multiple lines, I will... AGAIN answer **YES**. You can try:

```bat
command 1 && ^
command 2 && ^
command 3
rem You can continue like the above.
```

Learn more about the ampersands (double [`&&`] and single [`&`]) and the `||` symbol in question [What does "&&" in this batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889954/what-does-in-this-batch-file): I would suggest you to take a look at the second answer.