# How to disable input in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console, console-application, windows-console

I have a batch script (mine) that launches another batch script (theirs). Their batch script queries user input as part of the process, and I do not have access to modify it.

I need to suppress their batch script from querying input, meaning that when their batch script outputs: `Press enter for step 2...`, I want the user to be unable to interact with the script using their keyboard, hence the script should look like it's frozen.

**How do I call their script from my script in such a way that the user is unable to interact with the input requests of their script?**

Comment: try with `echo something|their.bat` ?

Comment: Are you trying to get over `PAUSE` statements? If the script takes user input such as "Enter the number of users", then you will need to echo that to stdin as @npocmaka suggested.

Comment: Almost...I want stdin to be always empty, disconnected with the user keyboard.

Comment: `call their.bat < nul` However, this method causes that _all input_ be completed with empty data, not suspended...

Comment: That worked for me actually, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually summing up the comments to make this not an unanswered question. You can try using the `|` (pipe) operator:

```
echo Haha! You will not be able to press any key!! | their.bat
```

Which will redirect `STDOUT` (Standard Out) of command `echo Haha! You will not be able to press any key!!` (`Haha! You will not be able to press any key!!`) to `STDIN` (`Standard Input`) of command `theirs.bat`.

Or, even read from `nul`:

```
their.bat < nul
```

I recommend reading https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html and [What does "&&" in this batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889954) (second answer is better here.).